# RewriteRule apply on particular directory

Tags: php, getmethod

This is the code used in .htaccess,

`RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/?$ /blog/index.php?a=$1 [NC,L]`

I want to apply it on a particular directory, I can't apply this rule, but currently it redirect not found urls of whole website to `domain/blog/index.php`

Comment: You just need to add a RewriteCond before the rule to apply it only if the condition is met

Comment: What have you tried so far to make this work? Why is this tagged with PHP and "getmethod" while not being tagged with htaccess?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use RewriteCond. When ever you want to apply a Rule to a specific condition.

For example,

```
# Include in the next line all folders to include
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  (folder1|folder2|folder3) [NC]
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/?$ /blog/index.php?a=$1 [NC,L]
```

or the other way around by adding a !

```
# Include in the next line all folders to exclude
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  !(folder1|folder2|folder3) [NC]
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/?$ /blog/index.php?a=$1 [NC,L]
```

Also, keep in mind that in some cases Wordpress overights the htaccess file

In some cases adding the custom stuff to a block prevents that but not always. It depends on what plugins are in use.

```
## BEGIN - My Custom Redirects
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
.....
</IfModule>
## END - My Custom Redirects
```